# OpenCV RGB2HSV color space convertion gives wrong results, colors aren't similar

Tags: python, opencv

Why the color space conversion goes wrong (images are not roughly similar) when I use OpenCV `COLOR_RGB2HSV` and goes right when using `image.convert('HSV')` ? What I'm doing wrong?

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('picture_1.jpg')

img1=cv2.imread('picture_1.jpg')
img2=cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img3=cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
img4=cv2.cvtColor(img3,cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(16, 6), subplot_kw=dict(xticks=[], yticks=[]))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)
ax[0][0].imshow(img1)
ax[0][0].set_title('BGR', size=16)
ax[0][1].imshow(img2)
ax[0][1].set_title('RGB', size=16);
ax[1][0].imshow(img3)
ax[1][0].set_title('HSV', size=16);
ax[1][1].imshow(image.convert('HSV'))
ax[1][1].set_title('HSV', size=16);
```

I got this results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSV is scaled differently from how you might expect in **OpenCV**. When your data is `np.uint8` it can only be in the range 0..255, so Hue values are divided by 2 and instead of 0..360 as you might expect, they range from 0..180.

By the way, mixing up a load of `matplotlib` in your question already about PIL/Pillow and OpenCV reduces the likelihood of getting an answer - best to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV assumes images are in BGR format in both imwrite and imshow methods. So it handles the HSV matrix as BGR when saving or showing an image.
Another thing is in OpenCV documentation they say that,
"For HSV, Hue range is [0,179], Saturation range is [0,255] and Value range is [0,255]. Different softwares use different scales. So if you are comparing OpenCV values with them, you need to normalize these ranges."
You can find it [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html)